# Issue with parsing svg inside bootstrap tooltip title

Tags: svg, tooltip, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to add an icon by svg to my tooltip but the tooltip keeps ignoring it.

```
<input class="form-control bg-transparent" type="password"
                           name="password" autocomplete="off" id="passwordInput" data-bs-custom-class="tooltip-inverse"
                           data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-exclamation-triangle text-white' viewBox='0 0 16 16'><path d='M7.938 2.016A.13.13 0 0 1 8.002 2a.13.13 0 0 1 .063.016.15.15 0 0 1 .054.057l6.857 11.667c.036.06.035.124.002.183a.2.2 0 0 1-.054.06.1.1 0 0 1-.066.017H1.146a.1.1 0 0 1-.066-.017.2.2 0 0 1-.054-.06.18.18 0 0 1 .002-.183L7.884 2.073a.15.15 0 0 1 .054-.057m1.044-.45a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767z'/><path d='M7.002 12a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0M7.1 5.995a.905.905 0 1 1 1.8 0l-.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 1-1.1 0z'/></svg> Some tooltip text!" data-bs-html="true"/>
```

but actually I see only the text "Some tooltip text!" without the icon.

tryied also manually by js, and still ignoring it

```
new bootstrap.Tooltip(passwordInput, {
            placement: "top",
            html: true,
            title: '<div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-exclamation-triangle text-white" viewBox="0 0 16 16">' +
                        '<path d="M7.938 2.016A.13.13 0 0 1 8.002 2a.13.13 0 0 1 .063.016.15.15 0 0 1 .054.057l6.857 11.667c.036.06.035.124.002.183a.2.2 0 0 1-.054.06.1.1 0 0 1-.066.017H1.146a.1.1 0 0 1-.066-.017.2.2 0 0 1-.054-.06.18.18 0 0 1 .002-.183L7.884 2.073a.15.15 0 0 1 .054-.057m1.044-.45a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767z"/>' +
                        '<path d="M7.002 12a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0M7.1 5.995a.905.905 0 1 1 1.8 0l-.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 1-1.1 0z"/>' +
                    '</svg>'+
                " " +
                translationUtils.getTranslation("tCapsLockIsOn") + "</div>",
            id: tooltipId,
            trigger: "manual"

        }).show();
```

[image]

nothing found on the docs

Comment: @enxaneta But I can also add html inside it, if I will use divs for exampple it will work ok. it happened only with svg.

Answer (score 0):

```
new bootstrap.Tooltip(inputSelector, {
            placement: "top",
            html: true,
            title: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-exclamation-triangle text-white" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M7.938 2.016A.13.13 0 0 1 8.002 2a.13.13 0 0 1 .063.016.15.15 0 0 1 .054.057l6.857 11.667c.036.06.035.124.002.183a.2.2 0 0 1-.054.06.1.1 0 0 1-.066.017H1.146a.1.1 0 0 1-.066-.017.2.2 0 0 1-.054-.06.18.18 0 0 1 .002-.183L7.884 2.073a.15.15 0 0 1 .054-.057m1.044-.45a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767z"/><path d="M7.002 12a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0M7.1 5.995a.905.905 0 1 1 1.8 0l-.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 1-1.1 0z"/></svg>' + translationUtils.getTranslation("tCapsLockIsOn"),
            id: tooltipId,
            trigger: "manual",
            sanitize: false
        }).show();
```

Solved!
Bootstrap has config called "sanitize" that was removing my svg, when adding it as false, solved the issue.